# Speed up swarmplot/stripplot in seaborn > 0.9.0?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

After an update to seaborn 0.11.1 from 0.9.0 I noticed that `swarmplot` and `stripplot` became MUCH slower when adding a hue variable.

I am plotting ~4000 data points across ~100 categories and 3 hue levels.

In seaborn 0.9.0 this was much faster and took ~5 seconds. Now it takes 30-60 seconds.

Without adding a hue variable, the speed is comparable between the versions.

I determined this changed with the update to 0.9.1 by trying various versions of seaborn.
Is there a new setting that I missed that I can use to recapitulate the old performance in newer versions of seaborn?

EDIT:
Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
dfTest = sns.load_dataset('planets')
sns.stripplot(data=dfTest,
                  x='method',
                  hue='number',
                  y='orbital_period',
                 dodge=True)
    plt.legend().remove()
    plt.ylim([0,1000])
    plt.xticks(rotation=80);
```

[image: stripplot example]

This dataset it not quite as big (1000 rows) as the one I am working with (4000 rows) but it illustrates the point.

Answer (score 2):

My guess about what caused this is the change in 0.9.1 to match vectors based on pandas index information rather than position, which I think happened in a for-loop over the hues within each category and therefore probably didn't scale well to many categories. I don't know how you would avoid it in 0.11.1 but the good news is that those functions have been [rewritten since then](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2429) and a simple example with the dimensionality that you describe runs quickly (~1 s) now.

Without seeing an example of exactly what you're trying to do it's a little hard to advise, but my guess would be that in most situations with 100 categories you can't really see the jitter/swarming, so you should be able to get away with using `scatterplot`...

Comment: I added an example now. I would not mind using scatterplot. you are right I don't really need the jitter once I use that many categories. But it didn't seem straightforward to add dodging by a hue variable with scatterplots.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant 'those functions have been rewritten since then'. Will these changes be part of a new release? Or can I somehow make use of them already?